# Send value from MainViewController to ContainerViewController?

Tags: ios, segue, uicontainerview

I'm developing an app, I want to send value from MainViewController to ContainerViewController. I've added delegate from MainVC to Container(A) and i defined one method to send values. But this method is not working. I think my usage of `prepareForSegue` is wrong. Is delegate usable for two way communication between two Views with different methods ? 
I've added image to describe my situation.

Thanks for helpings.

**Here is my MainVC code block;**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"layersViewSegue"]) {
    [ (LayersViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];


}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addLayerSegue"]) {
    [ (AddLayerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];


}
}
```

**Container A code block**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"layersViewSegue"]) {
    [ (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];

}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

YourDestinationController.h // container

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *assignableString // any object/variable
```

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"])
    {
        YourDestinationController *yourDestinationController = (YourDestinationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        yourDestinationController.assignableString = /* your string */;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I send value from B Container to mainVC and than from mainVC to Container A. I try call prepareForSegue when Select containerView but I receive this problem  "'There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?' " How can I do ?

Comment: Never faced this issue... Really difficult to get the problem with provided information.